# Textfield duplicates text

Tags: android, libgdx, textfield

I got a textfield that the user can write text in, and the text is saved into preferences so that the text remains the same as they left it. But I´ve must´ve done something wrong because when it flushes the preferences and you re-enter that screen again the text have been duplicated and placed up on eachother, and some part of the stored text isn´t removeable.

This is how I´ve done:

```
 public final String fieldString = "";
public final String areaString = "";

//


final TextField textField = new TextField(prefs.getString(fieldString),textstyle);

    textField.setX(250);
    textField.setY(800);
    textField.setMaxLength(23);
    textField.setWidth(textWidth);
    textField.setHeight(textHeight);
stageText.addActor(textField);
```

I flush the prefs as the user clicks the backbutton to the mainscreen.

```
btnArrow.addListener(new ChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {


                    game.setScreen(0);


                    //Saves the entered text.


                    prefs.putString(fieldString, textField.getText());
                    prefs.putString(areaString, textArea.getText());


                    prefs.flush(); 

                }


            });
```

Comment: You can use prefs.removeString(..);

Comment: I am assuming the keys being empty is just for this sample. I haven't used libgdx but this seems odd

Comment: user3541465 51 - Yes. But I still need the users entered text to show. The problem must simply be that every time the backbutton flushes a new string is created and stored?

Comment: I think you're failing to clear `stageText` of the previous TextField prior to adding the new one upon re-entering the screen. Or you could keep a reference to the original one and change its text.

Comment: Both those ways sound promising. How would they be done? How do I clear stageText?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the navigation code, from your description it sounds like multiple text fields are getting added on top of each other each time you return to the screen.